# Can a public constructor built inside a friendly class be accessed from a different package?

Tags: java

```
package mypackage.pack1;
class PackClass {
  public PackClass() {
  System.out.println("I'm creating a packaged class");
  }
}
```

then import the package containing this class.
Can the public constructor be used even though the class is not public? Or do i need to be inside the same package to use it?
I couldn't try it out myself because I can't figure out how to save the package with eclipse in my ClassPath to import it, so if you can help out with this too it would be great.
Thanks

Comment: You can't import packages, only classes and only if they are accessible (static imports are irrelevant here). http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not access the public constructor from a different package since the class modifier is default.

Comment: making it public allows you to access it within the package.If you make it private then you will not able to access it even within package and of course default modifier allows to access being in same package.

Comment: @NewProgrammer it does not matter whether constructor itself is public or just "default" (or package-private). The only point is, you can allow / restrict access to everything by just changing the class visibility if everything inside is public.

Comment: the only exception to this being static void main when set to public

Answer (score 1):

The top level modifier is valid, i.e. in your example  *default modifier* is valid even though the constructor is public. Try interpreting your code like this:

*default* class A
{
   *public* A() {}
}

Your public constructor is **encapsulated** within a default-level accessible class, so how can a class from a different package access to this public constructor without breaking the capsule? It simply cannot. Try it yourself.

Comment: I would, but as I said I'm having trouble saving my package in CLASSPATH to be able to use it...and by having trouble I mean I'm not able to do it yet
Any idea?